# Fatal error: Call to a member function row_array() on boolean

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-query-builder

Please i have an issue with codeigniter. when i try to log here is the result

Below is the my code :

```
    $sub_and = '';

    if($this->location_parent == 0){
        $sub_and = "and g.idlocation_fk IN (".$locids.")";
    }else{
        $sub_and = "and g.idlocation_fk IN (".$locids.")";  
    }


    if(($this->session->userdata("user_group_fk") == 1) || ($locids == '')){
        $sub_and = '';
    }       


$sql = "select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(g.idgroup)) as group_id 
            FROM groups g
            JOIN group_users gu ON gu.idgroup_fk = g.idgroup
            WHERE gu.status = 0 and gu.iduser_fk = $iduser $sub_and";

    $results = $this->db->query($sql);
    $results = $results->row_array();
    return $results;
```

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 0):

you have error in concatenation. 
try with following.

```
$sql = "select GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(g.idgroup)) as group_id FROM groups g JOIN group_users gu ON gu.idgroup_fk = g.idgroup WHERE gu.status = 0 and gu.iduser_fk = $iduser." ".$sub_and";
```

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer but its not working for me

Comment: try to run your query in phpmyadmin and let me know what error you are getting.

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '" ".$sub_and" LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

*Make sure `$iduser` is available in your method and `$locids` should be an array of values*

```
$this->db->select('GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(g.idgroup)) as group_id');
$this->db->from('groups g');
$this->db->join('group_users gu', 'gu.idgroup_fk = g.idgroup');

$this->db->where('gu.status', '0');
$this->db->where('gu.iduser_fk', $iduser);

/* $locids must be an array like $locids = array(1,3,4);*/
if (! empty($locids))
{
   $this->db->where_in('g.idlocation_fk', $locids);   
}

$row = $this->db->get()->row_array();
print_r($row);
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html